# Ggplot problem printing class POSIXct and coloring by group R

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, posixct

```
value<-c(2,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,7,7,2,1,4,1,14,44,34,33,66,7,87,99,90,45,69,77,0,65,2)
LSL<-80
DateTime<-c("2020-11-24 15:59:22 GMT", "2020-11-24 16:29:22 GMT", "2020-11-25 08:02:36 GMT",
"2020-11-27 08:27:58 GMT", "2020-11-27 08:57:58 GMT", "2020-11-27 09:27:58 GMT",
"2020-11-27 09:57:58 GMT" ,"2020-11-27 10:27:58 GMT", "2020-11-27 10:57:58 GMT",
"2020-11-27 11:27:58 GMT", "2020-11-27 11:57:58 GMT" ,"2020-11-27 12:27:58 GMT",
"2020-11-27 12:57:58 GMT" ,"2020-11-27 13:27:58 GMT", "2020-11-27 13:57:58 GMT",
"2020-11-27 14:27:58 GMT" ,"2020-11-27 14:57:58 GMT" ,"2020-11-27 15:27:58 GMT",
"2020-11-27 15:57:58 GMT" ,"2020-11-27 16:27:58 GMT" ,"2020-11-27 16:57:58 GMT",
"2020-11-27 17:27:58 GMT", "2020-11-27 17:57:58 GMT", "2020-11-27 18:27:58 GMT",
"2020-12-20 06:36:38 GMT", "2020-12-20 07:06:38 GMT" ,"2020-12-20 07:36:38 GMT",
"2020-12-20 08:06:38 GMT" ,"2020-12-20 08:36:38 GMT" ,"2020-12-20 09:06:38 GMT")
DateTime<-as.POSIXct(DateTime)
Group<- c("Hungry","Hungry","Hungry","Hungry","Laughing","Laughing","Laughing","Laughing","Hungry","Hungry","Angry","Angry","Angry","Angry","Laughing","Laughing","Laughing","Laughing","Happy","Happy","Happy","Happy","Angry","Angry","Angry","Angry","Laughing","Laughing","Laughing","Laughing")
DATA<-data.frame(cbind(DateTime,value,Group))
DATA$Months<-months(DateTime,abbreviate=F)

idx <- c(0, diff(as.numeric(DATA$DateTime)))/60
i2 <- c(1,which(idx >30), nrow(DATA)+1)
DATA$grp <- rep(1:length(diff(i2)), diff(i2))

jpeg("TEST.jpg", width=8000, height=4000, res=300)
ggplot(DATA,aes(x=DateTime,y=value))  +
geom_line(aes(group=grp))+
geom_point(aes(colour=Value<LSL))+
scale_colour_manual(name="value<LSL",values=setNames(c('red','black'),c(T,F)))+ 
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=LSL,linetype="Lower Specification Limit"), color = "red")+
scale_linetype_manual(name = "Specification Limits",values = c("solid"),guide=guide_legend(list(color 
= c("Specification Limits"))))+
labs(x = "Dates", 
   y = "value",
   title = "Value Out Of Specifications ") +  
scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%a-%d", date_breaks  ="1 day",
               sec.axis = dup_axis(name="Hours",labels = scales::time_format("%H:%M"),breaks 
=scales::date_breaks("5 hours")))+

facet_wrap(~ Months,scales = "free")+

theme(axis.text.x = element_text( angle = 90, vjust = 1, hjust=1))

dev.off()
```

This is my not running code I've tried to run this but always gives me this error

```
Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only
```

Well I tried to fix this but I couldn't. Is this any way to run this? I also want the line that will be printed to be colored (One line multiple colors) by the Group variable if it is possible thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The data type of `DateTime` gets lost in `DATA<-data.frame(cbind(DateTime,value,Group))` if you replace this by `DATA <- tibble(DateTime, value, Group)`.

Comment: As you're using colour for the geom_point already, you can use a different point shape and fill aesthetic for the geom_point and then colour for the geom_line - e.g.: ```ggplot(DATA,aes(x=DateTime,y=value))  +
geom_line(aes(group=grp, colour = Group))+
geom_point(shape = 21, aes(fill=value<LSL))+
scale_fill_manual(name="value<LSL",values=setNames(c('red','black'),c(T,F)))+ ...
```

Comment: Weird, there should not be any additional points. Shape 21 should work [here's a site with few examples](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape). There could be two reasons: either the points are too small to see the fill colour - you might try "size = 4" or, other problem could be the output device (at least in some occasions I noticed that in the standard R graphics window things are shown a bit differently than when writing to files).